# vQmod won't modify an OpenCart template file

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

I am running OpenCart 2.1.0.2 and have installed vQmod 2.5.1. For some reason vQmod won't modify one of my template files. In case it bears any relevance, I am using a premium template called "Fastor" from ThemeForest.

Let's say that I create an XML file (using vQmod XML File Generator) to modify something on this file:

```
catalog/view/theme/fastor/template/common/header.tpl
```

I can modify whatever I want in that file and it works OK. However, if I try to modify this file with vQmod:

```
catalog/view/theme/fastor/template/common/header/header_05.tpl
```

Nothing happens. I can edit the file manually on my computer, upload it via FTP and I can see the changes on the live site. So I know I am editing the right file.

I've tried clearing the vQmod caches and even my browser cache, still nothing.

I'm not sure what it is I'm doing wrong, because vQmod otherwise works fine?

Comment: share your vqmod xml code

Comment: Just look in your VQMod log or Modification log, depending on which VQMod parser you use. Problem might be with your search string, not with file name or XML.